# How to prevent flickering on a SlickGrid when updating data and using momentum scroll?

Tags: ios, grid, slickgrid, flicker, momentum

I had created a SlickGrid to be used on an IOS device. I update the data at an interval of 1 second (through a web socket). I had added momentum scrolling on it by adding the following css:

```
 .slick-viewport
 {
     overflow-y: scroll; 
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
```

This causes the grid to flicker with every update!! It stops flickering if I remove the above css. It also stops flickering if I stop updating data (with momentum scroll turned on). You can replicate the issue by adding the above css in the "Highlighting and flashing Cells" (or Example 14 in the Examples folder) example given in SlickGrid wiki.

*Grid flickers on every update when I add the above css to enable momentum scroll on an IOS device. How can I remove the flickering?*

Comment: Can you explicitly state what your question is?

Comment: @Ed Grid flickers on every update when I add the above css to enable momentum scroll on an IOS device. How can I remove the flickering??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a DataView instead of providing data directly to the grid:
    `dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();`

Comment: Did you lazy-load the data or did the data exist on the client? As I have understood DataViews they should only be used when data is available on the client